# Passing data from tableViewCell to another VC

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass the text of a tableViewCell into another VC and use that text to determine a displayed image , but regardless of what I do it only ever displays the text and image of the last cell. Here is my code, any help would be massively appreciated.

import UIKit

class TheExerciseLibrary: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    exerciseTableView.delegate = self
    exerciseTableView.dataSource = self
}

var exercises = ExerciseLibrary()
var mainCell = UITableViewCell()

@IBOutlet weak var exerciseTableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return exercises.exerciseArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeCell2", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = exercises.exerciseArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3285208941, blue: 0.5748849511, alpha: 1)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)

    return cell
```

}

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let displayVC = segue.destination as! Exercise

    if mainCell.textLabel?.text == "Bench press" {
        displayVC.navTitle = "Bench Press"
      displayVC.image = UIImage(named: "BenchPress")!
          }

    if mainCell.textLabel?.text == "Barbell squat" {
        displayVC.navTitle = "Barbell Squat"
      displayVC.image = UIImage(named: "BBSquat")!
      }
    if mainCell.textLabel?.text == "Shoulder press" {
        displayVC.navTitle = "Shoulder Press"
        displayVC.image = UIImage(named: "BBShoulderPress")!

    }
}
```

}

On the next VC it always displays Shoulder press and the shoulder press image regardless of what cell is clicked.

The segue is set up via the ctrl drag method in story board.

Thank you.

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"segue",sender:exercises.exerciseArray[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let item = sender as! String

    let displayVC = segue.destination as! Exercise

    if item == "Bench press" {
        displayVC.navTitle = "Bench Press"
        displayVC.image = UIImage(named: "BenchPress")!
    }
    else
    if item == "Barbell squat" {
        displayVC.navTitle = "Barbell Squat"
        displayVC.image = UIImage(named: "BBSquat")!
    }
    else 
    if item == "Shoulder press" {
        displayVC.navTitle = "Shoulder Press"
        displayVC.image = UIImage(named: "BBShoulderPress")! 
    }
}
```